# Using collision_map in environment_server for arm_navigation

Tags: ros, planning-environment, collision-map, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As what I read it should be possible to put the kinect pointcloud into the  [collider node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collider), and then put the [published costmap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collider#Published_Topics no new page) into the environment_server of [planning_environment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment).

I see both pointcloud and costmap in `rviz`, but the validity checker ignores it. Regarding to `rosnode`, the `environment_server` isn't listening to a `collision_map` typed topic at all.

What I configured:

- In my once generated [*planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_robotname[_real].launch*](https://github.com/felix-kolbe/uashh-rvl-ros-pkg/blob/master/scitos_haw_schunk_arm_navigation/launch/planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_scitos_haw_schunk_real.launch) I set `use_collision_map` to true.
- I had to remove the 4-line-include`<include file="$(find

> planning_environment)/launch/environment_server.launch">` and run it separately, because else one node keeps crying and nothing works:

```
[ INFO] [1332518882.807188537, 1332518882.801862955]: Waiting for environment 
server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1332518882.935278639, 1332518882.932450056]: waitForService: Service 
[/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30363/using-collision_map-in-environment_server-for-arm_navigation/) by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was, that *use_collision_map* actually wasn't enabled for the `environment_server`.

I had used `roslaunch --args` to produce a command for that 4-lines-include. But that was totally ignoring the *include args* like *use_collision_map*, therefore it didn't crash because of no map, but also was working without a map.

The `collider` has to be started with the following to match the `environment_server`'s default topic. Like it's in the default launch file.

```
<remap from="collision_map_out" to="collision_map_occ" />
```

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1